# How to change the alignment of a PdfPTable?

Tags: pdf, itext

I want my text in the pdf to start from the top-left side of the margin.
I tried the following

```
PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(2);
PdfPCell cell=new PdfPCell();
cell=new Phrase("Sa m ple thing ");
table.addCell(cell);
```

But I get the table in middle

Comment: I changed the title of your question and I removed the Netbeans tag, as Netbeans is totally irrelevant with respect to your question.

Comment: *"I want my text in the pdf to start from the top-left side of the margin."* - then why do you use tables at all? Why don't you add paragraphs or phrases directly to the document? If there is a reason, @Bruno's answer shows how to do it, but if there is none, simply don't use tables here.

Comment: I want to print the data in a legal sized label. So I used tables for that purpose

Answer (score 2):

The default alignment for the `PdfPTable` object is `Element.ALIGN_CENTER`. If you want to change the default, you can use the `setHorizontalAlignment()` method as explained in the documentation. See for instance the [examples of chapter 4](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4) of the old "iText in Action" book, more specifically, the [TableAlignment](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4#199-tablealignment.java) example:

```
public void createPdf(String filename)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfPTable table = createFirstTable();
    table.setWidthPercentage(50);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    document.add(table);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    document.add(table);
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    document.add(table);
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
```

Given the fact that you are asking such a trivial question, I assume that you are new at using iText. In that case, please consider starting with iText 7 instead of with the old iText 5. iText 5 is in maintenance mode, which means that no new functionality will be added, whereas iText 7 is actively developed.

Choosing iText 7 is more future-proof than choosing iText 5. Take a look at the [table chapter](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2) of the iText 7 tutorial for more info about tables in iText 7.

Comment: Thanks I will look after it. By the way as you said I am new to it.